# Online Users Cannot See Public Folders in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-office-365, public-folders

We have 3 Public Folders setup in O365 Exchange Online. The users who are using client-side Outlook (the installed app) can see those folders with no problem, but the online users (those who use Outlook online) cannot see public folders.

I have seen instructions that say to login to O365, Go to Outlook > Folders > More and click on Public Folders. The problem is that "Public Folders" does not show up for those users. They don't show up for anyone using Outlook online. I can see the Public Folders in my local Outlook 2016 (the installed application), but I cannot see Public Folders when I'm logged into O365, Outlook online.

Am I simply looking in the wrong places? Is there a flag that I need to check to enable online users to see Public Folders?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a solution.
---------------- Might need more info Jono. Are you able see the picker when you right click on the Folder icon, e.g. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2015/09/16/new-public-folder-picker-for-owa/

Comment: @MithunAshok, Thank you for that. When I originally posted this, I had searched long and hard for an answer and I kept finding the solution that I put in the original post, the one that doesn't work. Thank you for the link; that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the O365 Web Client seems to have been updated, so I'm posting this answer here for anyone else who might need guidance.

You have to add the public folder you want to see to your favorites.

Right click on "Folders" on the left pane, then click "Add Public Folder to Favorites"
[image: O365 Add Public Folder to Favorites]

If you only use 1 or 2 Public folders this is an OK solution. No solution for those that use multiple -- you'd have to add all to your favorites. There is no way to add a root of a folder to your favorites and have all in the subtree be visible, either.